# Query for tables returns views too

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract the names of the tables I have.

The code below returns me tables AND views.

```
   SELECT  quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE table_schema='public'
```

**Question**

How can I obtain just the table names and exclude the views?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/infoschema-tables.html) (emphasis mine):

> The view `tables` contains all tables **and views** defined in the current database.

You can use the `table_type` column to exclude views:

```
SELECT quote_ident(table_name) as tab_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_type != 'VIEW'
```